# Как отправить через POST переменную без input

Tags: php, post

Есть форма, которая передаёт значения select-ов через POST-запрос, но надо к ним добавить ещё массив, который формируется в процессе создания этих select-ов. Как это сделать? Возможно это не записывать в значение тестового input-а, после чего его отправлять? :)

**first.php:**

```
<form class="forma" action="second.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="NamesUsers">
<?php
      $name = $_SESSION['login'];      
      $availableNames = array();
      if ($_SESSION['RolOfUser'] == 'admin'){
        $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login != '$name'");
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
          echo "<option value=\"".$row['login']."\">" . $row['login'] . "</option>";
          array_push($availableNames, $row['login']);
        }
      }else {
        $sqlModer = mysqli_query($db,
        "SELECT login FROM users INNER JOIN roli ON users.id=roli.UserId where users.login !='$name' and roli.RolOfUser !='admin'");
        while ($rrow = $sqlModer->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<option value=\"".$rrow['login']."\">" . $rrow['login'] . "</option>";
          array_push($availableNames, $row['login']);
        }
      }
?>

    </select>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name = "SetRol">
        <option value = "admin">Сделать администратором</option>
        <option value = "moderator">Сделать модератором</option>
        <option value = "user">Понизить до ЮЗВЕРЯ</option>
      </select>
    </div>  
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Изменить роль">
</form>
```

**second.php:**

```
  $NameUser = $_POST['NamesUsers'];
  $NameRol = $_POST['SetRol'];
  $allowed = array("admin", "moderator", "user");
  //$availableNames = $_POST['$availableNames']; ???
  if(in_array($NameRol, $allowed) and in_array($NameUser, $availableNames)){
    $sql = "UPDATE roli SET RolOfUser = ? WHERE UserId = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = ?)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param("ss", $NameRol, $NameUser);
    $statement->execute();
  }else{
    echo "<div class=\"message center\"><p>Невозможный пользователь или роль</p></div>";
  }
```

Comment: <input type="text" size="5" name="'.$value['id'].'[]">  для текста так [] делал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать через POST в данном случае небезопасно, могу обмануть и передать что то другое)))
Вы можете определить какой список должен быть на основании значения $_SESSION['RolOfUser'] и сделать запрос в базу данных для получения этого списка.

```
$name = $_SESSION['login'];
$availableNames = [];
if ($_SESSION['RolOfUser'] == 'admin'){
  $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login != '$name'");

}else {
  $sqlModer = mysqli_query($db,
    "SELECT login FROM users INNER JOIN roli ON users.id=roli.UserId where users.login !='$name' and roli.RolOfUser !='admin'");
}
while ($row = $sqlModer->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_push($availableNames, $row['login']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Без вывода отправляемой информации в коде сайта - никак, но вы можете поступить неочевидно - отправлять форму на JS и перед отправкой добавить ей нужный параметр Пример на jq ajax

```
$('.sudmit-class').click(function () {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
        //    ВСЕ НЕОБХОДИМЫЕ ПАРАМЕТРЫ
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });   
})
```

Comment: Значит в headers записывать что-то вроде: `$('#selectUser').value;$('#selectRol').value;`
А как передать-то массив, если для этого метода `var name = "<? echo $json);?>";` необходимо чтобы скрипт выполнялся именно в **first.php**? Где `$json = json_encode($massiv);`

Comment: в headers должно быть ключ - значение, типо:

 `"headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "4e518b3a-1811-28a8-1750-d670e5bac8d3"
  }`

А вот прмиер как php массив скормить в js

https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/convert-php-array-to-javascript-array/

Comment: Значит итоговый код будет:`"headers": { "NamesUsers": namesUser, "SetRol":  setRol, "availableNames": avuser }` где   `var namesUser = $('select[name=NamesUsers]'); var SetRol = $('select[name=SetRol]')` ,а для того чтобы передать массив я должен этот код поместить в конец своего файла в тэг script `var avuser = <?php echo json_encode($userArray); ?>;`
Но ведь  чтобы это сработало на странице должно быть только одно `echo`, а у меня через него выводятся части select

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос только об HTML и форме, тогда сериализуйте данные и положите их в скрытый input
**Например:**

Если отправка при помощи jQuery
Тогда вы можете вписать данные в любой блок и затем через селектор и при помощи jQuery выбрать эти данные и отправить обработчику php

Comment: Так вопрос и состоял в том как это сделать без всяких скрытых input-ов. Да и потом, даже если я сделаю у input тип hidden, то он будет виден в коде элемента, что очень нежелательно

Comment: Если это конфиденциальная информация, пишите её в БД, по путно создавайте уникальный ИД для этих данных при помощи md5 + salt. По этой же схеме затем в обработчике формы получайте данные и делайте запрос к БД